# simple AJAX dropdown 2

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Ok this code seems to be working now (ajax getting the current selection) . But i now have another problem. When i use php $_GET method (for later database search), the output isnt just dropdown chosen word, but also generates another dropdown menu. There is also WAMP error - undefinex index for GET.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#select").change(function(){
        $.ajax({
                url: "test.php?selected=" +$(this).val(),
                success:function(data){
                    $("#results").html(data);
                }
            }
        )
    })
});
</script>
<select id="select">
<option> something </option>
<option> something2 </option>
<option> something3 </option>
</select>

<?php

echo $_GET['selected'];

?>

<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is arising because you're self-referencing in the ajax call without accounting for the postback. Also the initial page load will throw an undefined index error because the `selected` key does not exist in the `$_GET` collection.

At the top of your `test.php` file:

```
<?php
    if(array_key_exists('selected', $_GET))
    {
        echo $_GET['selected'];
        die();
    }
?>
```

Then remove your echo later on in your example.

Note that this is **only** to make your example work and show why it failed. Not to give a well-formed example of an AJAX request.

Comment: Thanks. So what do you suggest as a best solution? I would like to fetch data from database when item is selected from dropdown list and show it instantly without refreshing the site.

Comment: Well, as @genesis suggested, use `value` in your `option` elements, then when handling the posted data (see inside the `if` statement from my answer) query your database using the posted data. I would recommend reading up on `$.ajax` jquery calls, `post` as opposed to `get`, and general php tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

```
<option>
```

needs to have value

```
<option value="test">
```

Answer (score 0):

What is `echo $_GET['selected'];` supposed to display?
Can you give us some PHP code, as well?

And if you have an `undefinex index for GET`, it means that the array `$_GET` contains no key named `selected`. Where do `selected` come from?
If it comes from the JavaScript you gave us, then it should be `select` instead. (Also, naming your `select` with the keyword `select` is not recommended.)

Comment: Thats all PHP code I have. I was just trying to achieve that PHP would get selected option (through ajax) and check database for it. I was going to do the database thing later. Its not complicated :)